# Error al obtener los datos de una API en React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una aplicación para mostrar los datos del clima, 1 componente resuelve una api de ubicación y otra para mostrar los datos del clima dependiendo de esa ubicación.

Lo estoy haciendo con useEffect pero m**e sale error como que no estoy recibiendo los datos**.

Componente de ubicación:

Aqui lo que hago es obtener la ubicacion pasandole la longitud y latitud, retornandola y exportandola

```
 const getData= async (long, lat)=>{
  
      const promise= await fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${long},${lat}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGV4Y2FybG9zIiwiYSI6ImNrb2hzNmd6MjBudGQybmxsMHFybjNvZW0ifQ.VTlqEeCl-zmlMFe-5_fYJQ`)
        const results = await promise.json()
      return results
          }

  export default getData
```

Componente de clima:

Aquí obtengo la información del clima pasando el nombre de la ciudad

```
const getWeatherData= async(name)=>{
    const api = {
        key: "key",
        base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
      }

      const promises = await fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${name}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      const results = await promises.json()
      return results
}

export default getWeatherData
```

aquí ya junto los dos componentes en el useEffect pero el error mencionado anteriormente.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data){
    setLongitude( data.coords.longitude); //longitud
   setLatitude( data.coords.latitude)}) // latitud


  useEffect(()=>{


  getData(longitude,latitude).then(data=>{ //COMPONENTE1, aqui le paso la lon y lat 
   
console.log(data) //al hacer un console.log si me muestra los datos en consola correctamente

    let city_name=data.features[1].text  // guardo en una variable el nombre de la ciudad pero aqui me sale un error de **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined  at weather.js:27**
    getWeatherData(city_name) //COMPONENTE2 aqui le paso el nombre de la ciudad
          .then(result => {
            setWeather(result); //guardo los resultados del clima en una variable de estado
          });
  })
  },[])


[![aqui es el console.log(data)][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3Sl.png
```

Comment: podras mostrar el json que te devuelve en el console.log(data);

Comment: de donde estas sacando data.feautures[1].text, porque siguiendo tu api `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&APPID=5b881f6447593d97ee91f3b5027f1e09` no da el features y si quieres obtener el nombre de la ciudad, el campo `name` nomas es  data.name y aqui puedes usar un operador para validar si existe o no, `data.name ?? "no existe"`

Comment: En principio te recomiendo no compartir tus keys.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma interesante de obtener datos es utilizando una librería llamada [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)

Este pequeño ejemplo puede parecer un poco diferente pero es una mejor forma de obtener datos de una API, utilizando [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) y [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```js
    import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState([])
    const [capitalCity, setCapitalCity] = useState("city");

     useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get(`${urlWeather}${newAccessKey}&query=${capitalCity}`)
          .then((response) => {
            setWeather(response.data);
          });
      }, [newAccessKey, capitalCity]);

          ... 
};
```

Si quieres ver un ejemplo real más completo puedes acceder a mi repositorio en GitHub [aquí](https://github.com/kemilbeltre/Fullstack-course/blob/master/part2/dataforcountries/src/App.js)